# Transformation of variables to fulfill normality assumption before GAM

Tags: data-transformation, nonparametric, generalized-additive-model

We are running a GAM with highly skewed (and positive data) both in the dependent and in the independent variables. We have chosen to transform both the dependent variable (cubic root transformation) and the independent variables (log-transformation) to meet the normality assumption and be able to perform a GAM with Gaussian distribution family and identity link.
This option seems to give the best model performance, but we are unsure about the implications of transforming the variables instead of using a non- parametric GAM option.

Even if using a distribution other than Gaussian to deal with non-normality is possible, it seems that transformation of the dependent variable is common in the literature.
However transformation of the independent variables is less common since the use of smoothing splines make it less of a need.

I would be happy to hear your comments about it and any reference support you can provide.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not using the non-parametric form of the independent variable transformation ($f(X)$). Without it, GAM is the same as a linear regression. To your other point, it is certainly reasonable to transform the outcome variable using a log or a Box-Cox transformation, rather than one of the parametric link functions in the GLM family, but then you have to explicitly account for that transformation in the downstream processing of the fitted model (predicted values, marginal effects, etc).

Comment: What I mean is if log transformation of the independent variable is a reasonable approach (prior to GAM), or if is it redundant and unnecessary since GAMs' smoothing splines already deal with non-parametric data.

Comment: The log-transformation of the outcome variable is a valid modeling strategy even if transforming the covariates. GAMs are just a special class of covariate transformations, and the same rules apply.

Comment: Would you have any reference to back up that transformation of outcome variable and covariates is a valid modeling strategy? I could not find anything in statistical literature.

Comment: There is no need for a reference here. GAMs are just a family of transformations of the covariates. Just like you might use $X^2$, $X^3$, etc. Similarly, independent of covariate transformations, you would consider transforming the dependent variable, and it is no different for GAMs. In short, there is nothing special about GAMs for the questions you are asking.